# Why is the verb to be in the infinitive in 'Praise be to God.'?

Tags: grammar

Why is the verb to be in the infinitive in 'Praise be to God.'?

Other sentences that look similar are:

'May you be always in our presence.'

'May you be forgiven.'

But May + sub + infinitive of be is used to make a wish and 'Praise be to God' is more of a informative statement rather than a wish.

Comment: It’s being used in the present subjunctive, just as you have with *Long live the king*.

Comment: The other sentences are the Magical sense of _may_, used in wishes, blessings, curses, and other magical invocations, like "May this house be safe from tigers" or "May you spend eternity rollerskating on cobblestones". Fillmore discusses this sense of _may_ in his [classic lecture, "May We Come In?"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf).

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161302/that-be-construction/161322#161322) on the subjunctive.