# blessed be the mystery of love

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Would you explain the lyric "**Blessed be the mystery of love**" in the song "Mystery of love" by Sufjan Stevens please? Why the song writer use the word "**be**" instead of "**is**"?

*Full lyrics of the song*: https://genius.com/Sufjan-stevens-mystery-of-love-lyrics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the grammar behind "Thanks be to God"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84447/what-is-the-grammar-behind-thanks-be-to-god) It's an example of the formulaic subjunctive.

Comment: Thank you so so much

Comment: See also [Why is the verb _be_ in the infinitive in 'praise be to God'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178502/why-is-the-verb-to-be-in-the-infinitive-in-praise-be-to-god) and the duplicate.