# Why is the verb used without “-s” in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, infinitives, subjunctive-mood

> In order to help the system make a better guess of the corner locations,...

In this sentence, why is "make" not succeeded by "s"? It seems it is needed!

Comment: I think this is because it's a future tense. It (the system) will make a better guess. If it was present tense, then _the system makes_ would be correct.

Comment: @dave No. It's not a future tense and its "make" even in an unambiguous present such as "It helps the system make a better guess."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The construction used here is **help + object + bare infinitive**. Here are two more examples:

> Can you help me fix my bike?
>
> I helped my father cut the grass.

An equally grammatical equivalent to the above construction is to include the **to** before the bare form:

> Can you help me **to** fix my bike?
>
> I helped my father **to** cut the grass.

It is clear that the verbs *fix* and *cut* are infinitives and are therefore not determined by the number of the object (*system* in your example).

You could rewrite your sentence as:

> In order to help the system **to** make a better guess of the corner
>   locations,...

Comment: I wish Word grammar-check would learn that one. At least my incarnation of it is programmed to have inviolable subject-verb agreement at the expense of all else. As another example it would not like "One of our gnomes is missing" and want an "are". Pshaw. How many non-native speakers have been misled and corrupted thereby?

Comment: It should be added that omitting "to" in "help (to) infinitive" is AmE usage. BE tends to retain the "to". This lack of "to" made it complicated for the OP.

Comment: @Gábor: Actually, it looks like [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+me+find%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chelp+me+to+find%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chelp+me+find%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chelp+me+to+find%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20me%20find%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20me%20to%20find%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20me%20find%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20me%20to%20find%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows both AmE and BrE are dropping the "to", but AmE started doing it earlier and is further along in the process.

Comment: @Gábor I'm not convinced by that claim. To my British ears, "Help someone do something" sounds more natural than "Help someone to do something."

Comment: @David: According to the Ngram in my last comment, Gábor's claim would have been correct between around 1900 and 1950.

Comment: @David Pugh. I know that a lot of the regulars here hate _Word's_ grammar check with a passion, but I have found it increasingly accurate. My version (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 on Windows) correctly accepts "_One of our gnomes is missing_" and rejects "_One of our gnomes are missing_."

Comment: To me (american), having to sounds wrong.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected, language changes faster than we think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: 'In order to help the system make a better guess of the corner locations,' is an adverb telling us why we do something, not a sentence. The actual sentence follows this adverbial phrase. Adverbs do not require finite verbs.

In order to help the system make a better guess of the corner locations, we need to improve the 'corner location function'.

You can leave out the adverbial phrase:

We need to improve the 'corner location function'.

You cannot just write the adverbial phrase, that makes no sense:

In order to help the system make a better guess of the corner locations.

In order to [do something], I/you/she must/needs to/should [do something else]

Answer (score -1):

"Make" is subjunctive rather than indicative, meaning that instead of describing an action that definitely occurs, occurred, etc., it is a theoretical occurrence, or one that may or may not happen.

Example:

I am walking to the park to see my friend.

"Walk" is indicative, because it is currently happening, while "see" is subjunctive. It does not use "seeing" because it is what I am intending to do, but may or may not happen. (Note that "to" is used to denote purpose, not to set "see" off as an infinitive.)

Comment: Hi, Mark, and welcome to the site. I must admit I'm intrigued by your answer. I freely admit I don't know a *lot* about the subjunctive mood, but I wonder if you're not in the same boat. As a new user, it's wise to provide references for your answer, lest it be leading another down a wrong path. For example, [since I knew so little, I had to "show why"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161302/that-be-construction/161322#161322). We all go through that phase.

Comment: A very queer theory.

Answer (score -4):

For a better answer, it **does** look like the -s is needed because you're seeing it as "In order to help, the system make a better guess of the corner locations,...," which is the correct form to use, but you need the -s for "make."  The sense will still be the same, won't it.  Yeah.

Comment: No, that changes the sense in a different way. Your second sentence is an imperative addressing the reader. When the system is being helped in its attempt to guess, you can't actually have a comma.

Comment: Don't worry about that because look now!